# Image slider doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have attempted to create an image slider following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_P3Auq-U8c. I have not had any success and I am struggling to think of the reason why the slider will not work. Having gone through the code several times I can't spot any mistakes.

This first is from the head of web page.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/imageslider.js"></script>
```

Next is all the code that can be found in imageslider.js:

```
function Slider() {
$(".slider #1").show("fade", 500);
$(".slider #1").delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

var sc = $(".slider img").size();
var count = 2;

setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider #" + count).show("slide",{direction:"right"}, 500);
    $(".slider #" + count).delay(5500).hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, 500);

    if(count == sc){
        count = 1;
    }else{
        count = count + 1;
    }
},6500);    
}
```

In the main body of the page I have the following:

```
<div class="slider">
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="image1" border="0">
        <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="image2" border="0">
        <img src="images/image3.png" alt="image3" border="0">
        <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="image4" border="0">
         </div>
```

The css responsible is fairly simple:

```
.slider{
width:425px;
height:175px;
/*overflow:hidden;*/
margin:30px auto;
background-image:url('../images/loader.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}

.slider img{
width: 425px;
height:175px;
display:none;
}
```

Any guidance here would be superb, really scratching my head with this one!

Comment: You should make a jsfiddle.  Also, you have defined the slider() function, but it's never being called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a simple slider then you can check [Simple Slider](https://github.com/jcobb/basic-jquery-slider)

Answer (score 0):

i have used MenuCool sliders for a while now, and they're great. Really simple to customise as well. So give them a go, also a great way to get to know more about JavaScript! - [MenuCool JavaScript Slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)